# Support Game Theory SE on area 51

Tags: discussion, area51

This is a message to encourage anyone interested to support [the proposed Game Theory SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47845/game-theory) on area 51.

Math SE has been great at addressing the lack of a place to ask questions on game theory. However, todays' game theory relates to a lot of applied and empirical problems which do not have their place on MathSE. For clarity and effectiveness, I believe everyone could gain from clearly separating the topics.

If you have an interest in game theory and you also think game theory should have its own place outside of MathSE, do not hesitate to commit to the proposal on area 51!

Comment: So, did you get gamers to join and support, hoping for this to be about the academic aspects of being a gamer? :-D ["I'm writing my dissertation on the repercussions of using a buckling spring keyboard while playing Street Fighter..."]

Comment: Honestly, I think that GT is too localized in order to succeed on its own as an SE site. I doubt whether there will be enough noteworthy questions and/or answers on the site. But good luck!

Comment: I don't quite see how game theory relates to a lot of problems which DO NOT have their place on Math.SE."

Comment: Well, most game theory articles on the arXiv are in the computer science section. Some are even in the physics section.

Comment: @ Dreamer : I take your point. I hope you are wrong, but I am afraid you might be right, so I started an alternative proposal for a "Mathematical Social Sciences" Q&A http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64941/mathematical-social-sciences, hoping that this would have a better chance to reach the critical mass needed for a healthy SE site.